# Axios post method returning 404 status code

Tags: rest, express, axios

I'm trying to hit rest endpoint which requires multipart file as input parameter from Express. I'm able to hit this endpoint via Postman.
But this endpoint is returning 404 status code in Express. How can I resolve this issue ?

```js
const file = req['file'].buffer.toString('base64');
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file);
axios.post('http://localhost:10000/user/', form_data, {
  headers: form_data.getHeaders()
}).then((response) => {
  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", response);
  Id = response.data;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
  Id = null;
});

ERRROR:
=======
 data: {
      timestamp: '2021-05-21T04:43:10.860+0000',
      status: 404,
      error: 'Not Found',
      message: 'No message available',
      path: '/user/'
     }
  },
   isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you realize that `return Id` will never work because of the asynchronous nature of  `axios`, `.then()` and `.catch()`?

Comment: Actually, my endpoint retuurns Id . I need to use that Id in other function. And the endpoint is always returning 404. Actually, I'm calling restendpoint which is written in java from express.

Comment: My comment wasn't about the 404 - you do need to fix that first.  My comment was that when you fix that, the structure of your code will not work.  You cannot do `return Id` the way you are attempting to.  `axios()` is asynchronous.  You have to use a promise or callback to communicate back the return value.  Your function will return BEFORE you have the Id and the Axios call will finish sometime later and give you the value.

Comment: ok.. will remove the return statement then

Comment: On the 404, there's nothing in your question that lets us know what might be going on here.  If you show the entire request that works via postman or show us the documentation or code for the endpoint, then maybe we'd have a better idea what is required in the request.

Comment: On the `return` issue, you probably want to do `return axios()...` and then put `return response.data` inside the `.then()` handler.  The `return axios()...` will return the promise that `axios()` creates so the caller can use that to get the value.  The `return response.data` will set the resolved value of the promise to be your Id value.

Comment: Added restendpoint which is working on postman

Comment: Are you saying that you see `AXIOS ERROR: ...` in your Express app's logging?

Comment: Yes.. facing AXIOS ERROR .. Edited the error as well in the above query

Comment: Is your Express app running on the same host as you run Postman (ie is it running on your PC)? You're not running Express via Docker or any virtualisation software?

Comment: No .. running on the same PC